# Does CDI @RequestScoped prevent concurrency problems?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, cdi

Let us say we have a class:

```
@RequestScoped
public class FooService {
     private NonThreadSafeGenerator generator = new NonThreadSafeGenerator();

     public String generateId() {
          return this.generator.generateId();
     }
}
```

And we run our application under some servlet-container. Will it be thread-safe? In other words, is it guaranteed that RequestScoped's bean is always visible only within single thread?

Comment: How is the `generator`initialised?

Comment: @SteveC fixed that. Just in the initialiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed. Firstly you can take a look at CDI specification, at [6.3 Normal scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#normal_scope). Take your time reading it, it takes a bit of time but the conclusion is that normal scoped are basically thread-bound.

Then, to really convince you, let's take a look directly to Weld codebase. All implementations of normal scoped context are based on several abstract predecessor classes. If you do a bit of digging, you can come up with two of them - [`AbstractBoundContext`](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/3.0.2.Final/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/contexts/AbstractBoundContext.java#L29) and [`AbstractUnboundContext`](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/3.0.2.Final/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/contexts/AbstractUnboundContext.java#L28). Both use `ThreadLocal` to implement an underlying bean store - this is what will guarantee you the thread-based behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FooService` bean instance is guaranteed to be used by only one thread at a time.

However, it's still possible that `NonThreadSafeGenerator.generateId()` is not thread safe. It could for example be relying on static instance variables for state, or invoking a method on another object or class that does this.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide any kind of documentation references. Because just answering: "yes, it is guaranteed" is not convincing.

Comment: You missed the most important point. You asked if your class was thread safe and right now it seems that it is not as you have provided it with a member object that is *not* thread safe (judging from it's name)